# Writing a highly performant Cache

Tags: java, caching, optimization, memory, concurrenthashmap

I wrote a stock market simulator which uses a `ConcurrentHashMap` as a cache.

The cache holds about 75 elements but they are updated and retrieved very quickly (~ 500 times a second).

Here is what I did:

**Thread 1:**

Connected to an outside system which provides me with streaming quotes for a given stock symbol.

**Thread 2 (callback thread):**

Waits till data is delivered to it by the outside system. Once it gets the data, it parses it, creates an immutable DataEntry object, caches it and sends a signal to thread3.

**Thread 3 (Consumer thread):**
Upon receiving the signal, retrieve the DataEntry from the cache and uses it. (It is part of the task to not let thread2 push data directly to thread3).

```
public final class DataEntry{

      private final String field1;
      private final String field2;
      //...
      private final String field25;

      // Corresponding setters and getters

}

public final class Cache{

        private final Map<String, DataEntry> cache;

        public Cache( ){
           this.cache = new ConcurrentHashMap<String, DataEntry> ( 65, 0.75, 32 );
        }

        // Methods to update and retrieve DataEntry from the cache.
}
```

After running it through a profiler, I noticed that I am creating a *lot* of `DataEntry` object. And therefore eden is filling up very quickly.

So, I am thinking of tweaking the design a bit by:

**a)** Making the `DataEntry` class mutable.

**b)** Pre-populating the cache with empty `DataEntry` objects.

**c)** When the update arrives, retrieve the `DataEntry` object from the map and populate the fields.

This way, number of `DataEntry` object will be constant and equal to the number of elements.

**My questions are:**

**a)** Does this design have any concurrency issues that I may have introduced by making the `DataEntry` mutable.

**b)** Is there anything else I can do to optimize the cache?

Thanks.

Comment: You can access a ConcurrentHasMap over one million times per second and it won't have much impact if you are only accessing it 500 times per second.

Comment: I would only increase the partition size if you expect to have close to 16 or more cores accessing the Map at once.  If you are using less than say 4 cores accessing the map at once (and not doing anything else), its unlikely to make much difference.

Comment: Why is it a problem to have Eden fill up quickly? Are you actually experiencing problems due to Eden GC?

Comment: Allocating short lived objects is extremely cheap in Java so that alone wouldn't be worry some to me. You can reuse the Data entries, but still have to reinsert them newly so I doubt this will make much difference.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I wouldn't worry about the speed of ConcurrentHashMap

```
Map<Integer, Integer> map = new ConcurrentHashMap<>();
long start = System.nanoTime();
int runs = 200*1000*1000;
for (int r = 0; r < runs; r++) {
    map.put(r & 127, r & 127);
    map.get((~r) & 127);
}
long time = System.nanoTime() - start;
System.out.printf("Throughput of %.1f million accesses per second%n",
        2 * runs / 1e6 / (time / 1e9));
```

prints

```
Throughput of 72.6 million accesses per second
```

This is far beyond the access rate you appear to be using.

If you want to reduce garbage you can use mutable objects and primitive.  For this reason I would avoid using String (as you appear to have far more strings than data entries)

Comment: Thanks Peter. One more question if I may, if I make DataEntry mutable, I have to lock the map while I add it to the map, no? Or can I wrap the mutable DataEntry with AtomicReference? Cheers (BTW, love your blog).

Comment: For highly concurrent systems, the default concurrent hashmap wouldn't be a good idea, but I agree that from the description this doesn't seem likely either (I'd consider anything with more than a few dozen threads highly concurrent here YMMV). From the description a hashmap seems a strange choice anyhow.

Comment: If you are using a mutable DataEntry, I would only add it once (preferably on start up) Do you need more than one per instrument, ever? Cheers about the blog. ;)

Answer (score 1):

It sounds like you're using a `ConcurrentHashMap` when what you *really* need is something like a concurrent queue — say, a [`LinkedBlockingQueue`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/util/concurrent/LinkedBlockingQueue.html)?

Comment: Hi, actually I do need a map as I want the interested parties to poll the new data rather than push it to them.

Comment: Hm... I'm not sure that a map is still the best data structure for that. Have you thought about simply using separate queues for each "interested party?"

Answer (score 1):

- a. Yes, it does. Mutable `DataEntry` objects could be updated without the reader noticing, which will lead to inconsistent states.
- b. Yes, you can: make a mutable `DataEntryCache` that returns immutable `DataEntry` on request. This way you'll create new `DataEntry` objects on reads, not on writes. `DataEntryCache` could internally cache the immutable `DataEntry` that it constructs and returns, and invalidate that "cache" on mutating calls.

Edit: I am assuming that the reason you are caching (as opposed to creating a queue between threads 2 and 3) is that the consumer thread may read other entries in addition to the one of which thread 2 sends the notification. If this assumption is incorrect, you may not need a cache at all.

Comment: +1, although your answer to b looks like a race condition to me

Comment: Hi, I need a map so i can ask the interested parties to poll for the new data rather than push it to them.

Comment: @kdgregory this operation needs to be synchronized inside `DataEntryCache`.

Answer (score 0):

**a)** In my code object creation often manifests itself as bottleneck, so I think your own idea of reusing `DataEntry` objects is worth implementing too. However, as kdgregory commented, simply overwriting current elements will lead to inconsistent entries being read. So, when updating an entry, instead write to a new or a if available a reused idle (say idle for a couple of minutes) entry and put that into the map. After putting the new entry into the map, put the old entry on some kind of idle list. To be totally safe, reading threads must not be allowed to access the DataEntry delivered by the cache, after e.g. 1 minute. If the threads may block, they should copy the DataEntry objects, perhaps reusing own objects for this.

**b)** Your current design is modular but involves many context switches because the threads reflect the modules. I would try a design where a single request is served from beginning to completion by a single thread. A request could be the full processing of a new `DataEntry` object. Concurrency design patterns achieving this are [Leader/Follower](https://stackoverflow.com/q/3058272/280314) and [Half-Sync/Half-Asynch](http://www.cs.wustl.edu/~schmidt/PDF/PLoP-95.pdf).

Comment: "I don't see obvious concurrency issues" - what happens if one thread is reading values from the object while another is writing values?

Comment: @kdgegory, thanks. That *was* obvious ;). I updated my answer.