# Notification Child to Father Thread in C

Tags: c, multithreading, posix

I'm working with a Thread Pool. So I'm looking for a simple and efficient way to notify the father that a child has finished its job and that it's ready to work on another. Is there a way to do this?

The use of Condition Variable is only half-duplex (from father to child(s)) and the use of signals is totally NOT recommended.

What you suggest?

Thanks in advance.

Comment: "*The use of Condition Variable is only half-duplex*" then why not us another condition (per child) to make it "full-duplex"?

Comment: Can Child use Condition Variable? I knew that they could not...

Comment: I guess you could you static status flag (e.g. one bit per child) which access is protected against race conditions.

Comment: @TheNobleSix why do you need full duplex, if what you want is to only notify parent that child has finished (so it's one way communication)?

Comment: It is traditional to use the term 'parent' rather than 'father'.

Comment: I don't want full duplex. The use of Condition Variable stops the parent and I don't want it too. The use of flag is interesting and can be implemented via mutex.

Comment: @TheNobleSix You are saying child/parent and thread pool - are you using threads or processes?

Comment: You are right about terminology. I used to use this terms with processes, but right now I'm talking about Threads.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think you're solving the problem other way round, unless you don't want to implement something like the [Leader/Follower pattern](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3058272/explain-leader-follower-pattern), in which the threads take turns being leaders. This looks good on paper, but I've found it rarely to be efficient for ephemeral tasks due to the amount of locking required. Using `signalfd` or other form of waiting is also not exactly great due to the context switching. To sum it up, define *efficient* in order to propose a correct solution.

The simple thread-pool pattern can get away with just greedy consumers and no child-to-parent notification.

```
parent:
    task = wait_input()
    lock_queue(q)
    push_queue(q, task)
    signal_workers()
    unlock_queue(q)

worker:
    while is_active:
        lock_queue()
        task = pop_queue(q)
        unlock_queue()
        do_task(task)
```

Depending on your implementation, the `signal_workers()` can be analogous to `pthread_cond_signal` to wake up *any* thread, the queue locking must be blocking. This way the clients will either wait on the lock or process tasks. 
If you want to terminate them, you should set a flag, and broadcast them.
You can also use read/write locks and synchronize on the condition.
TL;DR, you should use locked queue instead of parent distributing jobs on-demand.

Once again, you should use a locking strategy based on your workload. It's a very different task to coordinate long-running jobs on something like [SLURM](https://computing.llnl.gov/linux/slurm/), where child-parent notification is a good idea, and a thread pool where it is not.

Answer (score 1):

You can typically do it through a `pipe`. The father will "own" the read-side, the child will push on the write-side.
Father process will wait for notifications via `select`.