# Leader/Follower pthread implementation in a server

Tags: c, multithreading, concurrency, pthreads

I'm trying to implement a basic server based on the leader/follower concurrency architecture. 
I originally sought to just create a thread pool and create a queue of the threads, but after reading this answer ([Explain "Leader/Follower" Pattern](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3058272/explain-leader-follower-pattern)), I feel like my algorithm is incorrect because the selected answer claims that a mutex is unnecessary.

The idea behind leader/follower, is that you initialize a threadpool, and one thread serves as the "leader" thread, and the rest are "follower" threads. In a server, the leader thread will be listening for incoming connections, while the follower threads all rest. When the leader thread detects an incoming connection, one of the resting follower threads will be promoted into the new leader thread, while the former leader accepts the connection and serves the request. When the former leader thread has finished serving the request, it becomes a resting follower thread.

However I can't see any way of implementing this without using a mutex and condition variable. Currently my implementation uses a threadpool and just allows every thread to accept new connections within a mutex.

Can someone please provide a high level explanation of the leader/follower implementation?

Here's some code that I wrote of my current implementation.

```
#define THREAD_COUNT 10
pthread_mutex_t request_tx;

int main(int argc, char* argv[])
{
    pthread_t threadA[THREAD_COUNT];
    pthread_mutex_init(&request_tx, NULL);

    //initialize server socket stuff

    for (int i = 0; i < THREAD_COUNT; ++i)
    {
        pthread_create(&threadA[i], NULL, rest, NULL);
    }

    for (int i = 0; i < THREAD_COUNT; ++i)
        pthread_join(threadA[i], NULL);

    return 0;
}

void* rest(void* kargs)
{
    int client_fd;
    struct sockaddr_in cli_addr;
    socklen_t sin_t = sizeof(cli_addr);
    while (1)
    {
        pthread_mutex_lock(&request_tx);
        client_fd = accept(server_fd, (struct sockaddr*) &cli_addr, &sin_t);
        if (client_fd > 0)
            serve(client_fd);
        else
            pthread_mutex_unlock(&request_tx);
    }
}

void serve(int client_fd)
{
    pthread_mutex_unlock(&request_tx);
    // serve request here
    ...
}
```

Comment: You've not got very close to creating an MCVE ([MCVE]), though you added some code just as I was about to say "you've provided no code".  You have unlocking issues with the mutex in the fragment you show.  Unless there is a `pthread_mutex_lock(&request_tx);` at the end of `serve()` — before every path out of the function — the final `pthread_mutex_unlock(&request_tx);` in `rest()` unlocks an already unlocked mutex unless `client_fd` is zero or negative (in which case `serve()` is not called).  This doesn't inspire confidence.

Comment: Part of it is because even if I fixed the issue with the locks, I have no idea if this is even a proper way of implementing the architecture. Can you shed some light on the implementation at a higher level?

I'll edit in some more code to show the threadpool initialization, but it's nothing extraordinary.

Comment: I debated between "unclear what you're asking", "too broad" and "MCVE" as close reasons.  It is not clear to me what `serve()` does; it is not clear to me what `rest()` does — it looks like it might be the thread function for `pthread_create()`. I'm not sure where the threadpool is. The cross-referenced question has a selected answer that claims "no synchronization necessary", but there is synchronization that's necessary; managing two threads both returning to an empty thread pool — or an all-other-threads-busy thread pool — at the same time (a) could happen and (b) requires synchronization.

Comment: No; I can't shed light on the algorithm at a higher level; I'm not familiar with it, never having heard of it until I looked at this question.

Comment: Thank you for commenting. I'll clarify this question with a more explicit description of leader/follower. The code is fairly irrelevant at the moment until I have an idea of how to implement the architecture itself. To be clear, this is not (yet) a coding question. I am looking for a higher level explanation of the algorithm so that I can begin to code it; the code that I've edited in so far is just a barebones example of my current implementation technique.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The linked answer is wrong.  Synchronization is definitely necessary *somewhere*.  In your example, you could remove the mutex because `accept` will block in the kernel, and (most?) implementations will activate exactly one thread for an incoming connection.  However, there is still some synchronization inside the kernel.

Your example is a bit misleading because the leader/followers pattern is typically used to distribute individual *requests* on multiple connections to a thread pool, not connections.  At this point, things become considerably more complex because a follower that has finished processing needs to tell the leader that a new connection needs watching.  If you are restricted to standard POSIX interfaces, this can be quite involved.  (With `epoll`, it should be possible to hand off most of the complexity to the kernel.)

In general, I would be cautious to adopt event handling patterns from the 90s.  Architecture has changed significantly since then: NUMA machines are no longer rare, systems can handle tens of thousands of threads within a single process quite comfortably, and other event handling interfaces such as `epoll` are available.

Comment: Is my example implementation code generally correct then?

Comment: For handling incoming TCP connections? Hard to tell. If the mutex wake-up policy is reasonably close to LIFO, it should work reasonably well, I think. If it's more like FIFO, it's probably not so great because this approach continuously wakes up different threads even under low load.

Comment: Removing the mutex completely seems to work just as well (or even faster). Thanks for the answer =)